# Simple collapse / expand using jquery within a php foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery

having a bit of trouble with a simple collapse/expand as the elements I'm try to do this with are within a foreach loop, and any element I create it's created for each list item, therefore, giving it a container is proving difficult.

PHP:

```
echo '<div class="cat_holder">';
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);


    foreach($ffs as $ff){

        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){

            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)){

echo '<div data-toggle="collapse" class="cat_header_holder collapse in">';
echo '<h1 class="lead">' .$ff. '</h1>';
echo '</div>';

            listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);    

            }else{


?><div class="cv_group"><?php

 echo '<a target="_blank" class="cv_item" href="'.$dir.'/'.$ff.'">'.$ff.'<span class="pull-right add_shortlist"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>';


?></div><?php

   }    
  }
 }
}

listFolderFiles('pdf');
 echo '</div>';
?>
```

JS:

```
   $('.cat_header_holder').click(function(){
    $('.cv_group').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Generated HTML:

```
<div data-toggle="collapse" class="cat_header_holder collapse in"><h1 class="lead">Title</h1>
</div>
<div class="cv_group">
<a target="_blank" class="cv_item" href="#doc">click here</a>
</div>

<div class="cv_group">
<a target="_blank" class="cv_item" href="#doc">click here</a>
</div>
```

cv_group is supposed to be hidden and onclick cat_header_holder, show cv_group.

The issue is that when clicking on cat_header_holder all cv_group's are displayed and not the one for that category.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Echoed html within a recursive function! Thats going to be fun to maintain.. Please do yourself a favour and have your function return a tree structure as an array, then iterate the array to build you html. At least then it will be readable, and the javascript problem can be diagnosed.

Comment: Thanks for the information, however not quiet sure how to do that. But i don't think this is a js problem it's a structure problem with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your final HTML will be somewhat like below you can check this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.cat_header_holder').click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.cat_header_holder').slideToggle('slow');
  });

});
```

```css
.cv_group {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-toggle="collapse" class="cat_header_holder collapse in">
  <h1 class="lead">Some Text 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="cv_group">
  Some Contents 1 - 1
</div>
<div class="cv_group">
  Some Contents 1 - 2
</div>
<div data-toggle="collapse" class="cat_header_holder collapse in">
  <h1 class="lead">Some Text 2</h1>
</div>
<div class="cv_group">
  Some Contents 2 - 1
</div>
<div class="cv_group">
  Some Contents 2 - 2
</div>
<div class="cv_group">
  Some Contents 2 - 3
</div>
<div data-toggle="collapse" class="cat_header_holder collapse in">
  <h1 class="lead">Some Text 3</h1>
</div>
<div class="cv_group">
  Some Contents 3
</div>
```

Here via `$.nextUntil()` we are targeting the next DOM elements i.e. associated div which need to be toggled.

Comment: That's where we hit the issue, is because the cv_group div is within the foreach loop is repeating it for each a tag within it. therefore only displays one result and not all the a tags.

Comment: @Kez - sorry but i didn't get you. can you please post the generated HTML if above solution doesn't work for you.

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad explanation. I have updated the question with the generated html code.

Comment: so you mean to say that there can be n number of `cv_group` between two `cat_header_holder`? and you want to show all of them?

Comment: @Kez - can you check it now?